# Como fazer inner join com Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu estou estudando `Laravel` e não estou conseguindo ***fazer/entender*** como fazer `join` e apresentar os dados. Todos os estudantes que estão em uma turma com os nomes, código da turma e descrição da situação final.

> [image: Modelo]

Modelo: TurmasHasEstudantes

```
public function turmaid() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(TurmasIdentificacao::class, 'id', 'turma_id');
}
```

Controller: TurmasHasEstudantesController

```
$turmax= $turmas_has_estudantes->turmaid;

print_r($turmax->codigo_turma);
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

> Property [codigo_turma] does not exist on this collection instance.

Se eu retirar o `->codigo_turma` eu consigo visualizar todos os dados da turma.

Eu preciso obter:

> `turmas_has_estudantes.id, turmas_has_estudantes.turma_id,  turmas_has_estudantes.estudante_id,turmas_has_estudantes.situacao_final_id, estudantes_identificacao.nome, turmas_identificacao.codigo_turma, situacao_final.descricao`

Comment: Luiz precisa colocar na sua pergunta todas as classes que fazem parte desse modelo de 4 tabelas! se não fica complicado responder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O uso do inner join não há a necessidade de preparar o relacionamento nos models (o que é sempre bom fazer).

Uma boa dica para preparar um inner join, seria primeiro checar como ele funciona direto no SGBD de sua preferência e depois colocá-lo no laravel, dessa forma você fica ciente do retorno e pode comprar se está correto

no seu caso seria

```
$resultado = DB::table('turmas_has_estudantes')
    ->join('estudantes_identificacao', 'estudantes_identificacao.id', '=', 'turmas_has_estudantes.estudante_id')
    ->join('situacao_final', 'situacao_final.id', '=', 'turmas_has_estudantes.situacao_final_id')
    ->join('turmas_identificacao', 'turmas_identificacao.id', '=', 'turmas_has_estudantes.turma_id')
    ->select('campos_a_serem_pesquisados')
    ->get();
```

um exemplo de inner join

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
    ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
    ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
    ->get();
```

Você pode ver mais sobre o inner join;

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Comment: Muito obrigado!!